# Testing Game Center's P2P Functionality over Bluetooth with the iPhone Simulator

Tags: bluetooth, ios-simulator, p2p, game-center, gkpeerpickercontroller

I would like to run and test P2P connectivity over Bluetooth via Game Center (`GKPeerPickerController`). I own an iPod Touch with OS 4.1 installed and am trying to connect it to the iPhone Simulator running on my Mac via Bluetooth, however they are not seeing one another. Bluetooth is on for the iPod and the Mac. Is this even possible? If so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it is possible, since bluetooth networking is currently not supported in the simulator.

check this for more detail..
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1